# Llamar funcion desde componente padre a componente hijo en vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Lo que necesito hacer es llamar una funcion en un componente hijo desde un componente padre.

En el componente padre tengo un boton y necesito que al darle click me abra un modal que esta en el componente hijo

Desde el componente padre tengo un boton este debe tener una función que me ejecute la funcion mostrar modal en el componente hijo

**COMPONENTE PADRE**

```
<template>
    <div class="">
        <button > CREAR USUARIO <button>
        <create-user> </create-user>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
    },
}
,
methods: {
}
}
```

El componente hijo contiene el modal y el codigo que muestra el modal

**COMPONENTE HIJO**

```
<template>
<div class="">
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="UserCreate">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Modal body..
                </div>
                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
    },
    }
    ,
    methods: {
        show_modal: function()  {
            $('#UserCreate').modal('show');
        },
    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42632711/73749

Answer (score 5):

Hay muchas formas de hacer esto:

- Utilizando ref para comunicar el padre con el hijo:

```js
var ChildComponent = {
  template: '<div>{{value}}</div>',
  data: function () {
    return {
      value: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setValue: function(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'child-component': ChildComponent
  },
  methods: {
    click: function() {
        this.$refs.childComponent.setValue(2.0);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child-component ref="childComponent"></child-component>
  <button @click="click">Click</button>  
</div>
```

En este caso, el padre ejecuta una funcion que pertenece al hijo. Algunos ven esto como un problema porque estas acoplando el padre al hijo.

---

- Usando un watch en el hijo y cambiando una propiedad

```js
var Child = {
  template: '<div>{{counter}}</div>',
  props: ['canI'],
  data: function () {
    return {
      counter: 0
    };
  },
  watch: {
    canI: function () {
      if (this.canI) {
        ++this.counter;
        this.$emit('increment');
      }
    }
  }
}
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'my-component': Child
  },
  data: {
    childState: false
  },
  methods: {
    permitChild: function () {
      this.childState = true;
    },
    lockChild: function () {
      this.childState = false;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<my-component :can-I="childState" v-on:increment="lockChild"></my-component>
<button @click="permitChild">Go</button>
</div>
```

En este caso, parece ser la solución mas aceptada por la comunidad.

---

- Usando eventos de padre a hijo

```js
var Child = {
  template: '<div>{{value}}</div>',
  data: function () {
    return {
      value: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setValue: function(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.$parent.$on('update', this.setValue);
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'my-component': Child
  },
  methods: {
    click: function() {
        this.$emit('update', 7);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
  <button @click="click">Click</button>  
</div>
```

Este ejemplo funciona en este caso, porque la instacia de VUE funciona como un bus, que es otra forma de hacer esto.

---

- Bus o VUEX: En este caso, la teoria es la misma, tener un ente externo que maneje los datos y asociar la instancia a ese metodo.

Este caso es similar al del watch, pero en lugar de comunicar la propiedad a una pasada por prop, la misma se comunica con un store externo. La ventaja de este metodo, es que las instancias estan totalmente separadas y ni el padre ni el hijo dependen del otro componente.

---

Todos los ejemplos estan sacados de las siguientes referencias:

[Con ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45463576/73749)
[Como bus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42633971/73749)
[Como emit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42634865/73749)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes abrir el modal con un método personalizado. para ello necesitas encontrar el componente hijo usando una referencia `ref` y luego puedes abrir el modal con el mismo método que ya tienes:

```
<div class="">
  <button @click="show_modal"> CREAR USUARIO </button>
  <create-user ref="modal"></create-user>
</div>

methods: {
  show_modal() {
    let element = this.$refs.modal.$el
    $(element).modal('show')
  }
}
```